# _Bool and bool: How do I solve the problem of a C library that uses _Bool?

Tags: c++, c, boolean

I've written a collection of data structures and functions in C, some of which use the _Bool data type. When I began, the project was going to be pure C. Now I am investigating using a C++ based GUI tool kit and have made the backend code into a library.

However, when compiling the C++ GUI the following error is emitted by the compiler:

`ISO C++ forbids declaration of '_Bool' with no type`

I initially thought I could search & replace `_Bool` to `bool` and create:

```
/* mybool.h */
#ifndef MYBOOL_H
#define MYBOOL_H

typedef _Bool bool;

#endif /* MYBOOL_H */
```

and then in any headers that use _Bool

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#else
#include "mybool.h"
#endif

/* rest of header... */
```

Until I realized this would be compiling the library with one boolean (C _Bool) data type, and linking against the library using another (C++ bool). Practically, this might not matter, but theoretically, it probably does (there might be some obscure system somewhere which doing so like this causes the universe to turn inside out).

I suppose I could just use an int and use 0 for false and 1 for true, and typedef it with something like `typedef int mybool`, but it seems unattractive.

Is there a better/idiomatic/standard way to do this?

Comment: Make that comment an answer, `bool` is how `_Bool` is intented to be used normally.

Comment: So I don't need to worry about the universe turning inside out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `#include <stdbool.h>` and use `bool`.

Comment: Your question is still entirely valid, as C99's "bool" is just a #define's alias of "_Bool", and the question of whether it's compatible with C++'s "bool" is indeed a relevant one.  Thus, I'm downvoting your self-answer.  :)

Comment: @James Morris: This answer makes no sense whatsoever. In C `bool` is just a macro substitute for `_Bool`, while in C++ it is a C++-specific type. There's no guarantee of C `_Bool` vs. C++ `bool` compatibility.

Comment: @AndreyT: There doesn't seem to be any guarantee that C `int` is compatible with C++ `int`. "Linkage from C++ to objects defined in other languages and to objects defined in C++ from other languages
is implementation-defined and language-dependent. Only where the object layout strategies of two language implementations are similar enough can such linkage be achieved.". I'd expect C and C++ compilers intended to be used together (such as gcc and g++) to make their `bool` and `int` types, among others, compatible.

Comment: If you can't answer without explaining yourself and being helpful without insults, than you shouldn't be posting.

Comment: @NeilRoy: Look at the OP's username. Now look at the answer's username. Now look at the answer's post date. Now ask yourself whether your rude comment achieves anything.

Answer (score 12):

If the C and C++ compilers you are using are from the same vendor then I would expect the C `_Bool` to be the same type as C++ `bool`, and that including `<stdbool.h>` would make everything nicely interoperable. If they are from different vendors then you'll need to check for compatibility.

Note, you can always test the `__cplusplus` macro in your header to determine whether or not the code is being compiled as C++, and set the types appropriately.

Comment: I can always test the __cplusplus macro in my header... Mmmm yeah, well spotted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461/interfacing-with-stdbool-h-c is an example of a case where they aren't compatible, though the problem there was a bad non-compiler-provided `stdbool.h` header.

Answer (score 9):

Formally, there's no solution for this problem. Type `_Bool` exists only in C. C++ language does not provide any type that would guarantee binary compatibility with `_Bool`. C++ `bool` is not guaranteed to be compatible.

The proper solution is not to use `bool` or `_Bool` in parameter declarations of C functions that are intended to be directly accessible (i.e. linkable) from C++ code. Use `int`, `char` or any other type that is guaranteed to be compatible.

Comment: I doubt that `int` or `char` _guaranteed_ to be compatible between C and C++. It can be stated to be true in documentation for compiler, but in general this assertion is false. And if documentation states compatible `int`s I don't see why it shouldn't say the same about `bool`.

Comment: @magras: No, C++ was originally created before _Bool was a part of C, so there is no reason why it should be compatible at all with later revisions.  `int` and `char` however are a part of standard C which C++ is based off of, so it absolutely should be compatible. `_Bool` was not added to C until the C99 standard, so unless otherwise stated, there is no reason why it should be compatible and it is reasonable to assume it is not. Similar naming conventions as `<stdbool.h>` adds does not equate to compatibility.

Comment: @NeilRoy: AFAIK current C++ standard based on C99. But does C++ standard requires _binary_ compatibility with C? If not, I'd say you are still wrong and binary compatibility is implementation defined, so only documentation can answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

I think that one must use `bool` in any project, in order to have compatibility with C++, if neccessary.

The data type `_Bool` in C99 exists to avoid conflicts with possible existent versions of `bool` that programmers could have been defined before the standard C99. 
Thus, the programmer can choose the better way to adapt their old C programs to migrate toward the new standard. 
Thus, I think that to use the word `bool` is the truly desire of C99 standarization commitee, but it have been forced to surround incompatibility issues by defining the ugly word `_Bool`.
This shows that the programmer probably have to use the "intended" word `bool` in his/her projects. It is the most logical word to declare a *boolean type* in a program.

In some cases, it could be good idea to keep a programmer preexistent definition of `bool` and, in other cases, it would be better to use the `bool` version defined in `<stdbool.h>`.
The programmer have to decide what is better in each case and besides, maybe, to consider if a gradual migration to `<stdbool.h>` is a good action to take.

If you are starting a project from zero, then probably the best approach is ever to use `bool` defined in `<stdbool.h>`.

Answer (score -7):

use `typedef int _Bool` for both your C and C++ code. I will be surprised if _Bool is defined as anything else.

Comment: _Bool is the C99 native type.

Comment: @JamesMorris: Not only is it the native type, its name is a keyword (assuming the C compiler supports C99 or later).